# Need to show "GRAND TOTAL" as a row header in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have a UNION report which contains 2 criteria. First Criteria contains all the individual values i.e. Student ID, Maths Mark, Science Marks. The 2nd criteria contains the TOTAL of Maths and Science Marks of all the students. In the 2nd criteria I need to show GRAND TOTAL as a ROW HEADER. How can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a pivot table:

1. Create a pivot table view, then Edit the pivot table view and move the attributes to the desired sections (Rows, Columns, and Measures). Drag and drop them until it looks like what you need.
2. In the pivot table view editor pane, next to the TOTAL column, change the Default Aggregation to Sum.
3. Next to the Student ID column (I presume it should be under the Rows section of the pivot table), click on the Sigma icon (**Σ**) icon.
4. Change the aggregation to display "Before" (I assume by Row header, you mean that you need the GRAND TOTAL to display to the left of the Student's marks.

Please let me know if this helps.